# Very strange error in priority queue in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue

I was writing priority queue as a part of preparation for the interviews and got an error I cannot trace.
My PQ code:

```
class PQ:
def __init__(self, capacity):
    self.a = [None] * capacity
    self.size = 0

def sift_down(self, i):
    while 2*i+1 < self.size:
        l, r = 2*i+1, 2*i+2
        j = l
        if r < self.size and self.a[r] > self.a[l]: j = r
        if self.a[i] >= self.a[j]: break
        self.a[i], self.a[j] = self.a[j], self.a[i]
        i = j

def sift_up(self, i):
    assert self.a[i] is not None
    assert self.a[(i-1) // 2] is not None
    while self.a[i] > self.a[(i-1) // 2]:
        self.a[i], self.a[(i-1) // 2] = self.a[(i-1) // 2], self.a[i] 
        i = (i - 1) // 2

def extract_max(self):
    m = self.a[0]
    self.size -= 1
    self.a[0] = self.a[self.size]
    self.sift_down(0)
    return m


def insert(self, x):
    self.a[self.size] = x
    if self.size > 0: self.sift_up(self.size)
    self.size += 1
```

And then I test it:

```
pq = PQ(6)
pq.insert(200)
pq.insert(10)
print(pq.extract_max())
pq.insert(5)
pq.insert(500)
print(pq.extract_max())
```

Everything works until 'pq.insert(500)':

```
File "pq.py", line 35, in insert
if self.size > 0: self.sift_up(self.size)
File "pq.py", line 21, in sift_up
while self.a[i] > self.a[(i-1) // 2]:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I have debugged values at positions `i` and `(i - 1) // 2` by every known method to me, asserts don't throw anything, I'm completely lost!

Comment: You can try to print self.a at the beginning of sift_up and self.a[i] and self.a[(i-1)//2] at the end of the while loop in sift_up

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the loop in `sift_up` if `i` is `1`, since once `500` reaches the root, there is no root's parent to compare it to (well, there sort of is, but it's `None` because you're using one-based indexing; I think you also have an off-by-one error in `sift_down` when you compare `< size` instead of `<= size`).